# Can a "C++ application signal python script on completion"?

Tags: python, c++, linux, signals, paramiko

I'm working on developing a test automation framework. I need to start a process(a C++ application) on a remote linux host from a  python script. I use the python module "paramiko" for this. However my c++ application takes sometime to run and complete the task assigned to it. So till the application completes processing, I cannot close the connection to the paramiko client. I wan thinking if I could do something like "the c++ application executing a callback(or some kind of signalling mechanism) and informing the script on completion of the task" Is there a way I can achieve this ? 
I'm new to python, so any help would be much appreciated.
thanks!

**Update:** Is it not possible to have event.wait() and event.set() mechanism between the c++ application and the python script ? If yes, can somebody explain how it can be achieved ?
thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm curious, why the quotes?

Comment: the way you described is how I would implement it as well; I'll upvote this to see if there are any other novel solutions

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to do this is to run both of them in a web server. Use something like Windows Web Services for C++ or a native CGI implementation and use that to signal the python script.

If that's not a possibility, you can use COM to create COM objects on both sides, one in Python, and one in C++ to handle your IPC, but that gets messy with all the marshalling of types and such.

Comment: Update: Is it not possible to have event.wait() and event.set() mechanism between the c++ application and the python script ?

Comment: technically, you could use Boost if you access to it on both the Python and C++ side for a more elegant, well documented IPC. If you don't need the processes to directly communicate or share memory with each other and just need to send information back and forth, you could use a socket. Just open up a socket on an unused port on both processes, and pipe the message over the socket.